# Java: Can't access method

Tags: java, methods, jgrasp

This is my first question on StackOverflow so please tell me if I'm not doing it right. Anyway, I've searched fairly thoroughly but can't seem to find an answer to my problem. The method I want to access won't be accessed on Java (Jgrasp). I'm not sure why since I feel like I'm using the right notation.

```
//PROJECT EULER Problem #4

//A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made
//from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

//Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class PE4

{


   public boolean isPalindrome(int five)
   {

      String word = Integer.toString(five);

      if (word.length()==5 &&word.substring(0,2).equals(word.substring(3,5)))
         return true;

      else if(word.length()==6 &&word.substring(0,3).equals(word.substring(3,6)))
         return true;

      else
         return false;

   }

   public static void NumberFinder()
   {

      for (int i=999; i>599; i--)
      {
         for (int j=999; j>i-300; j--)
         {

            if (isPalindrome(i*j)==true)
            {
               System.out.print(i + ", " + j + " = " + i*j);
               break outerloop;
               }
         }

      }
      return 0; 
   }


   PE4 tester = new PE4();
   tester.NumberFinder();


}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Anna

Comment: Does this code even compile? My guess is no. If that is the case, please post the compilation errors.

Comment: Don't you need a `main` method?

Comment: non-static method `isPalindrome` is being called from a static method. Suggested reading [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: `NumberFinder()` is `static`, `isPalindrome()` is not.  A `static` method can't call a non-`static` method because there's no instance on which to call it.

Comment: If it doesn't compile, post the error message. If it compiles but throws an exception, post the stack trace. If it runs but doesn't do what you want, tell us what it does. See [help/on-topic]

Comment: That last statement should be inside a method.

Comment: Your algorithm is also wrong because it will give `true` for `10210` and `false` for `10201`.

Comment: You also can't call methods outside of methods like you did at the end.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey Yes you can, if you surround them with additional braces.

Comment: Which the OP isn't doing... hence the modifier "like you did" in my comment.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey "outside of methods like you did" is the way i read it. Of course, you can now invoke plausible deniability.

Comment: Is any if that relevant to the OP? I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your top-level code inside the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  PE4 tester = new PE4();
  tester.NumberFinder();
}
```

This is just the first step, though. You must also remove `static` from the `NumberFinder` method and fix your algorithm, which doesn't actually detect palindromic numbers. Hint: `new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString().equals(word)`

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there is no code that can be executed outside of a class method scope. The main function of the class is executed by default when your program is run. Hence, you should add a main method to your class and call the NumberFinder method inside it.
Another point is that NumberFinder is static and hence it can be called directly on the class without creating an object of your class.
A third point is that static methods cannot access non-static methods hence your isPalindrome method should be static as well.